# How to animate rotating cube in C#?

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, cube

I would like to do something like this: a rotating cube on a form. I don't want to use any external library or dll, just pure .NET 3.5 (without directx). And a cube build with lines only. Could you please tell me how to do this?

I don't want to use external libraries because I don't need > 100 MB library to do this thing right? I want only to animate a rotating cube made with lines.

Comment: Could you expand on your requirements for why you don't want to use an external library? OpenGL or DirectX make this sort of thing vastly simpler than writing your own engine.

Comment: I've upadated my question. Feel free to answer.

Comment: Please Sir, could you send me the codes

Comment: I would like to do this in pure WinForms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you go about making a Cube in GDI+

C# 3D Drawing with GDI+ Euler Rotation

http://www.vcskicks.com/3d-graphics-improved.html

C# 3D-Drawing Cube with Shading

http://www.vcskicks.com/3d_gdiplus_drawing.html

Answer (score 4):

Study assignment? This can be done with some simple 3D maths. You just need to understand the basics of matrix algebra, 3D transformations, and 3D->2D view transformation. The [DirectX tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172485.aspx) covers this, but you can google for it and you'll get plenty of other tutorials.

**Added:** Just to clarify - I'm not suggesting to use DirectX or anything. You can do this with standard System.Drawing tools. You just need to understand the math, and that's explained in the DirectX tutorials.

Comment: Sorry but this tutorial does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using WPF and the 3D Tools source code released by the WPF team.

[3DTools](http://www.codeplex.com/3DTools)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WPF for your GUI:

1. Make an animated PNG of the cube using a graphics program.
2. Use the [APNG WPF Control](http://www.codeplex.com/apngwpf) to insert the image into your GUI.

This will yield a small assembly size and transparent background if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to represent 3d points. There is no ready struct for that in .NET unless you use directx or WPF.

Then with a standard euler rotation matrix applied to the points you get the transformed points. If you only do rotations you can get away with 3x3 matrix, but if you want translation you better use 4x4 matrices and homogenous points.

After this you need a way to project those 3d points to the 2d canvas. Depending whether you are using perspective or orthographic projection the projection matrix will look a bit different.

Answer (score -1):

Look into WPF in general, it will help you do this with a few measly lines of code.  You can also host a WPF window in Forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to do this in pure WinForms